# Should the “monitor” and “display” tags on Super User be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

**[Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_monitor)** and **[display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_display)**, for practical purposes, mean the same thing, right? I propose that these two tags be merged on Super User.

- [**`[monitor]`**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor) × 85
- [**`[display]`**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display) × 35
- [**`[monitor]`** & **`[display]`**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor+display)  7

Probably go with **`[monitor]`** as it's clearly the more popular one?

If you disagree, please suggest an alternative approach for solving the overlap between the tags. (In any case *most* current uses of the **`[display]`** tag are as synonym of **`[monitor]`**.)

Answer (score 10):

A quick glance at the questions tagged `display` showed at least (3) talking about the UI of an application, (2) talking about HDTVs, (2) talking about laptop screens (not normally referred to as "monitors"), and at least (1) talking about projectors.

"Display" is definitely *not* being used consistently as a synonym for "monitor".

Comment: Yeah, I noticed some of these too... Still, in the majority of cases it *is* used as a synonym. What would you think about merging them to diplay instead? (Obviously HDTVs, projectors, etc should have more specific tags too. An perhaps UI questions just shouldn't be tagged display.)

Answer (score 6):

Display could refer to anything you're displaying on. (Blackberry, iphone, touchtv, surface). Monitor refers to a specific TYPE of display

Comment: While technically true, it may be different in practice.

Comment: In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are not.

Comment: It *could*, but mostly it seems to be used interchangeably with monitor...

Comment: Perhaps they should be merged to display then? That would better suits ones like this, I think http://superuser.com/questions/235/which-notebooks-have-rgbled-displays

Comment: I'm suggesting that although some of those should probably be retagged, having two separate tags is still a good idea.

Comment: Apparently someone disagrees with me...

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at these questions. <kbd>display</kbd> and <kbd>monitor</kbd> should remain separate tags as in most cases they are not used as synonyms, and where they are there is enough users with tag editing power to fix the anomalies.

Where <kbd>display</kbd> and <kbd>monitor</kbd> is used, the most relevant one must be chosen and applied. I have gone through these and re-tagged so they should not be there.