# Related or synonymous tags: [monitor] and [screen]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The tag [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen) appears to be a mix of

- the same topics as [monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor)
- GNU Screen (which has its own tag [gnu-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen))

Should something be done about this? Perhaps separating the two into [monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor) and [gnu-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen), and then making [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen) a synonym for [monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor)? (I would be willing to work on the case-by-case retagging if that is decided on.)

Possibly related discussion: [Should the “monitor” and “display” tags on Super User be merged?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/558/should-the-monitor-and-display-tags-on-super-user-be-merged)

Comment: Screes seems to be used in conjunction with laptops, other `gnu` tags don't have the `gnu-` prefix. Maybe we could create a tag `laptop-screen`?

Comment: `[screen]` questions now no longer refer to GNU Screen

Comment: To clarify, I'm primarily wanting to point out that we have multiple tags being used for computer displays; the GNU Screen part is just a complication.

Comment: @KevinReid - I know. I completed the easy part. There were only 32(!) questions related to GNU Screen. I'll have to see the reminder later

Comment: Sathya: I'm confused. I've just now skimmed the newest 150 (out of 269) [screen] questions, and 33 of *those* were about GNU Screen. (Since I've taken the time to pick those out, I'll go ahead and retag them (as suggested edits) when I next have some idle time.) I'm not sure what you mean by “no longer” if not that you've retagged them all. Am I missing something about how StackExchange operates?

Comment: I did a mistake by checking quesions tagged only with `[linux]` + `[gnu-screen]`. Problem with editing these is that the question gets bumped to the homepage, which I want to avoid. There is a bulk-rename tool, but it doesn't work with mixed content like mentioned here. Give me some time. And, oh: please prefix @ to my user name (like: @Sathya) - else I will not be notified of your replies.

Comment: @Sathya any updates on this?

Comment: There's quite a lot of mixed content questions. There's no easy way to deal with this @studiohack

Answer (score 2):

Questions about `screen` now have the [gnu-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) tag, and [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen) is do with displays. That should solve it, although I'm not sure anyone wants to dredge through all the questions to check that its been sorted that way.

Comment: [screen] and [monitor] still exist as non-synonyms, which is the serious problem. They both have tag wikis, too.